# How to run gnome terminal child processes in differnet terminal

Tags: shell, gnome-terminal

I am writhing shell script. I want three script to run in different terminal. I wrote like this in shell script,

`gnome-terminal -x 1.sh`

`gnome-terminal -x 2.sh`

`gnome-terminal -x 3.sh`

Then parent terminal is waiting to finish for execution of `gnome-terminal -x 1.sh`. It wont proceed to next script while first script running. If I run these 3 script as background process, they run in 3 different terminal window but, I m not able to kill these 3 process.

I have to manually find there process id's and kill them. I don't want to do this. Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get their process id from the command line that launched them:

```
gnome-terminal -x 1.sh & pid1=$!
gnome-terminal -x 2.sh & pid2=$!
gnome-terminal -x 2.sh & pid3=$!
```